# Como pegar o valor de um variavel php e passar em um input java script

Tags: php, javascript

> tenho um formulario onde e preenchido os dados do cartão de credito e exibido no cartão!

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                    <?= $form->field($formPagamento, 'name')->textInput(); ?>


                </div>
            </div>


 //Name Input
            $(".inputname").keyup(function(){
                $(".fullname").text($(this).val());
                if($(".inputname").val().length === 0){
                    $(".fullname").text("Nome completo");
                }
                return event.charCode;
            }).focus(function(){
                $(".fullname").css("color", "white");
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você já está pegando o valor da variável PHP ao carregar a página, e quer colocar o valor dela em um input HTML, pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$valor?>" />
```

Agora, se você está querendo pegar o valor de uma variável PHP e passar para o código javascript recomendo que use uma requisição para o script PHP, utilizando axios, jquery, ou algo do tipo.

Então você teria um arquivo PHP.

pegaValorDaVariavel.php

```
<?php 
//Faz algum calculo ou consulta no BD
echo $minhaVariavel;
```

E com javascript você faria:

```
axios.get("pegaValorDaVariavel.php").then(function(response) {
    variavelJS = response.data
    //Faz outras coisas com a variavel...
})
```

Com jQuery use o ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Então o valor mostrado no input quero que apareça na imagem do cartão

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, seria tipo isso? https://jsfiddle.net/sngbrdtk/

Comment: isso mesmo, so que é o seguinte oi formulário ja e gerado automático pelo Yii, essa parte <?= $form->field($formPagamento, 'name')->textInput(); ?> dai como coloco para aparecer ?

Comment: Bom, ele gera um HTML com o input a partir desse comando, certo? Você precisa pegar o valor desse input pelo jQuery, certo? Então você pode pegar esse valor pelo nome do input, no caso você está passando 'name', então seria $("input[name='name']").val()?

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim tbm:

```
<script> var meusdados = '<?php echo $minhavariavle; ?>'; </script>
```